# Unstable search engine in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I come to you because I am optimizing my website that I created during my study hours, and I notice that I have a "ajax call error" error that sometimes appears on my search engine.
I’m still starting in Ajax, and I don’t understand why this is happening:/

Here is the code:

```
    //Timer - Une seule requête après saisie
    var attente = function(){
        var timer = 1000;
        return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    }();

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#autocompl").keyup(function(){
            var profileSearch = $(this).val();
            if ( profileSearch.length >= 2 ) {
                attente(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/profile/search/ajax/" + profileSearch,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        timeout: 10000,
                        // Fonction TIMER For no AJAX CALL ERROR
                        success: function(response){
                            var profileSearchs = response;
                            if (profileSearchs.length == 0) {
                                $('#result-auto-solut').html('No result');
                            } else {
                                html = "<ul id='solut' class='auto-complete-list'>";
                                for (var i = 0; i < profileSearchs.length; i++) {
                                    html += "<li><a href='/structure/"+profileSearchs[i].id+"'><b>"+ profileSearchs[i].name + "</b>  <small><i>"+profileSearchs[i].city+" "+ profileSearchs[i].postal+"</i></small></a></li>";
                                }
                                html += "</ul>";
                                $('#result-auto-solut').html(html);
                                $('#result-auto-solut').find('li').on('click', function () {
                                    $('#result-auto-solut').html('');
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $('#result-auto-solut').text('Ajax call error');
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000 );
            } else {
                $('#result-auto-solut').html('');
            }
        });
    });
```

I thank you in advance, and will answer you as soon as possible

Comment: What is the error you are getting (read error function of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ )?

Comment: the error I get is a plain text string.. $('#result-auto-solut').text('Ajax call error')
it happens when the time of the request is exceeded

Comment: From the jquery-site  _error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."_

Comment: Is your timeout too short? Is your backend taking too long? What parts have you debugged so far?